# WEB API 2.2 CORS and Windows Authentication issue on Internet Explorer 10 & 11 on GET request

Tags: internet-explorer, cors, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I have a JS client and a WEB API 2.2 service running on different hosts.

The service requires Windows Authentication and, due to the fact the service is on a different host, CORS must also be enabled. The JS client needs to perform an XHR GET request to the service (without any custom headers, so no CORS preflight needed)

**I am having trouble getting Internet Explorer 11 (11.576.14393.0) to work (neither version 10 does).** Note that Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m) and Firefox (50.0.2) do work, while MS Edge does not (38.14393.0.0)

I have enabled Windows Authentication and authorization in web.config. For now, it just requires a valid Windows user. Note that the OPTIONS verb config is commented out, as for the moment preflight is not needed.

```xml
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <!--<allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*"/>-->
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I initially enabled CORS using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet package, however it did not return the CORS headers to the client when Windows Authentication was enabled, therefore, for simplicity, I just added the CORS headers in web.config to be returned at each request to the Web API:

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://192.168.100.2" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Of course, I've set the value of the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to the JS client's domain.

My API controller is very simple and looks like this:

```cs
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Method()
    {
        return "api response";
    }
}
```

The JS client AJAX call with jQuery 2.2.4:

```js
    $().ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.100.73/WinAuthAndCors.WebAPI/api/default/method",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success: " + data);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("error");
            },
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        });
    });
```

Note that the code snippets in the question are all the customization done to plain client and Web API projects, the rest of them being boilerplate code.

**Here is the issue:**

Internet Explorer issues the GET request, correctly performs the CORS check but then gives up on the expected 401 response and does not continue performing the Windows Authentication negotiation.

- Disabling Windows Auth -> IE works
- Moving the service on the same host as the client (effectively disabling CORS) -> IE works

Chrome, for example, checks the CORS, then prompts for user credentials, then it correctly finishes the XHR (while doing the Win Auth negotiation in the background)

**Am I missing something or is IE simply unable to handle this case of CORS with Windows Authentication?**

---

Later edit: I tried to narrow the problem down as much as possible, so I created a simple HTTP server in Node and returned the following headers for the first request. Chrome prompts for credentials, while IE does nothing.

```js
    response.writeHead(401, {
        "WWW-Authenticate": "Negotiate",
        "WWW-Authenticate": "NTLM",

        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://192.168.100.2:8087",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    });
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? Latest update to windows has left me facing the same issue, and there doesn't seem to be much I can do to fix it. Chrome works fine, but IE just stopped.

Comment: From what I remember, I abandoned this approach and I used either basic authentication or avoided CORS. I remember doing some research to prove to the client that we cannot achieve this goal in a decent amount of time.

Comment: I am with the same issue. Is there a solution?